# why is my computer Beeping out of sleep mode

Tags: 12.04, lenovo

Tonight I put my computer in sleep mode like normal, and only after an hour of sleep mode my computer starting beeping (1 long beep then 2 short beeps) in this weird pattern. I run 12.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo ideapad s10 netbook.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo S10

One long and two short beeps, and a blank or unreadable LCD.
1. System board.
2. LCD assembly.
3. DIMM.

This seems to be a hardware defect.

Comment: Granted I had this system since 2009.

Comment: check if your DIMMS are properly seated (reseat them), clean the fans and the ducts if they are clogged up with dust (probably not that clean anymore after 5 years). It might just do the trick :-)

Comment: So I cleaned the fans (Lenovo has a door straight to the fans). I do not know what DIMMS are. if you could please explain in greater depth as to what they are that would help me a bit.

Comment: On an unrelated side note, when I cleaned the fan, The weird noises  coming from my PC are gone and now it is quiet again.

Comment: I checed all my drives with both SMART in Lenovo and SMART in ubuntu, both are coming up with extremely good marks.

Comment: the DIMMS are your memory modules: tiny circuitboards that are clicked into a socket on the big circuitboard. Often hidden behind a small panel at the bottom of your laptop.